# Where is the complete list of Shopify Webhook Topics

Tags: shopify-api

Note: *This question **is not** about how to retrieve the list of webhook topics an app is subscribed to.*

**Shopify API Version**: 2022-01 (Latest)
**Shopify Admin Api:** [REST Admin Api](https://shopify.dev/api/admin-rest/latest/resources/webhook)

The Shopify [Webhook Documentation](https://shopify.dev/api/admin-rest/2022-01/resources/webhook) lists several webhook topics by category.

Example:

[image: Shopify Events/Topcis]

### Subscription Error

Most all of the topics listed in the documentation can be subscribed to. However, if I try to subscribe to any of the `BillingAttempt` topics, Shopify returns an error:

```
Invalid topic specified: subscription_billing_attempts\success. 
Does it exist? Is there a missing access scope?
```

This particular webhook is for a custom app installed directly in the store. I have verified every available `access scope` has been enabled. As of today, there are a total of 62 available scopes and all are enabled.

### What is the Actual Question?

This isn't about troubleshooting the above error.

The question is specifically: Where can I find the complete list of available topics?

**Note**: Shopify includes a full list of topics in their error message. But, none of them are for `subscription_billing_xxx` topics. Maybe this is just a case where the API error has the most update to date list? And the docs are out of date?

Comment: In https://shopify.dev/api/admin-rest/2022-01/resources/webhook#resource-object there is a topic property under The Webhook object

Comment: @jegtugado you just provided a link to the **exact** same link in the post.

Comment: you can see on the Topic property the complete list of webhook topics including the  `subscription_billing_xxx` topics

Comment: @jegtugado - Thank you, but really not helpful if you actually read the question.

Comment: @MetroSmurf did you ever find a solution to this? We're facing the same problem right now.

Comment: @YassirEnnazk Nope. I ended up just experimenting with the topics listed in the docs and the topics listed in the error message. Nothing about billing, though.

Answer (score 1):

For the REST API: https://shopify.dev/api/admin-rest/2023-01/resources/webhook#event-topics

For the GraphQL API: https://shopify.dev/api/admin-graphql/2023-01/enums/WebhookSubscriptionTopic

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly this topics list is the one you are searching for: https://shopify.dev/api/admin-graphql/2023-01/enums/WebhookSubscriptionTopic

There is SUBSCRIPTION_BILLING_xxx topics:

- SUBSCRIPTION_BILLING_ATTEMPTS_CHALLENGED
- SUBSCRIPTION_BILLING_ATTEMPTS_FAILURE
- SUBSCRIPTION_BILLING_ATTEMPTS_SUCCESS
- SUBSCRIPTION_BILLING_CYCLE_EDITS_CREATE
- SUBSCRIPTION_BILLING_CYCLE_EDITS_DELETE
- SUBSCRIPTION_BILLING_CYCLE_EDITS_UPDATE